# Using listings to display regexes

Tags: listings

Is there any way to use the listings package (which I already use for Python) to highlight regexes? I.e. the regex appears in the document as if it were source code, but with some form of differentiation between (for example) literals and character classes, escaped control characters and real control characters.

It's not an uncommon feature in online regex testing tools.

For what it's worth, the regexes being discussed in my document are to be used for find/replace on LaTeX code, and will appear as `\lstinline`s.

**EDIT** background colour seems common for this:

- Regexbuddy

[image: regexbuddy screenshot]

- http://regexpal.com/ -- almost(?) identical to regexbuddy

[Sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com) apparently does character-colour highlighting:

[image: Sublime text screenshot]

This would seem to be (i) subjectively nicest, and (ii) most compatible with existing listings.

For reference https://www.debuggex.com/ has a nice visual parser which goes much further than anything (i) I had considered, and (ii) that would be possible in a text-based framework.

Comment: An example with some code? An image with the output you would like (may be a print from a webpage)?

Comment: @Manuel I'm looking for one that does it nicely - http://regexpal.com/ for example uses background colour which isn't great, and IMO doesn't do that too well.

Comment: Well, that, and an exemplary code, should definetly be in the question. Leaving the least possible work for the people who is going to answer.

Comment: @Manuel, I can't disagree, and I'm on the case (it's not a good google search given the uses of regexes *in* syntax highlighting), but I doubt anyone's going to write anything from scratch here, and if they've already written some personal code that they don't mind sharing, they won't need an example.

Comment: @ChrisH You're unlikely to get an answer unless you give at least some specs for the the type of syntax highlitghing you want.

Comment: @Jubobs the edit took longer than planned (in response to Manuel's original comment), but there's something there now.  Maybe I'll look at it myself if no-one's done it before -- but not until the task for which I want to use it is over.

Comment: @ChrisH Also some code in the question is welcome, so that, in case one wants to answer, doesn't need to write it himself (even if it's only two lines, it's better if you provide it). By the way, look at `minted`, `pygmentex`, `pythontex` and family; they let you use Pygments library in TeX.

Comment: @Manuel if you'd like to answer that listings won't do it, but minted etc. will, then that's fine by me, and if it's the only answer I'll accept it and do without highlighting.  If no-one has a quick answer I don't want to waste anyone's time writing the language style -- it's not that important to me, and it's not easy to see how it would work.  I think I'll leave the question in the spirit of "does such a tool exist already" rather than "please finish my code" for a little while.